# How to run spec for a gem in your path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, rails-engines

The Problem:

I have a Rails application and I can successfully run the RSpec suite using `rspec spec`. I've also made a neat little gem that also has a pretty little copyright next to it. Its not open source. Its a gem that belongs to that Rails application and that Rails application only.

Now, this gem has some specs and it also pumps out a nice string of green. So, to test the whole application I might do:

```
$ rspec spec
$ cd custom_gem && rspec spec
```

That's nice, but what if I want to run the whole suit from one line? Well I could do:

```
$ rspec spec custom_gem/spec
```

But, this doesn't work in my case because the gem is also a Rails engine. Due to this, it has to connect to a dummy application within the gem.

Now that you know this, I can finally ask my key question:

How do you run a spec for a rails engine and the spec for your main application given that your rails engine should also have a dummy application to test upon?

Answer (score 0):

If both of them are running correctly on their own, why not just make a bash alias?

```
alias test_all='cd /full/path/to/gem && rspec spec && cd /full/path/to/rails && rspec spec'
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this so that I can see my code coverage better, but this works.

Comment: Here's *one* reason not to do a bash alias: I don't want to change my CI configuration every time I add a new unbuilt-dependency Gem under `lib`. See http://pivotallabs.com/unbuilt-rails-dependencies-how-to-design-for-loosely-coupled-highly-cohesive-components-within-a-rails-application/ for a good description of what I'm working with/on. Using his example, how would I set up RSpec for the top-level `rails_app` so that it also ran (the correctly bundled, ideally) RSpec in each component directory under `lib`?